# API to display filled in tags in PNG format

Tags: docusignapi

We are looking for a way to have functionality similar to the following api method which returns a requested page in PNG format (non editable format):

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST API References/Get a Page Image.htm

but with the ability to display the values for any custom, etc. tags that have been filled in.  Currently, no tags or values are displayed regardless of whether they have been filled in.

Does any know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can bring back the tab values with the page image when the envelope is still in process, I think only completed envelopes will show that info.

You'll most likely have to make a separate API call to retrieve the recipient entered tab values. Have a look at the **Get Envelope Recipient Status** API call, and more importantly, it's one optional parameter.  Details of the call are:

**URL:**
`/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients`

**HTTP Method:**
`GET`

**Parameters:** 
`The only required parameter is the envelope ID. If the optional query include_tabs is set to true, the tabs associated with the recipient are returned. If the optional query include_extended is set to true, the extended properties are returned.`